# How to set array elements after I have initialized it?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am looking for a simple way to set the elements of an array after it is initialized. I have tried this :

```
package com.ehsan.app;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = new int[6];
        test = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

However compiling this gives error :

```
Error:(7, 16) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(7, 17) java: not a statement
Error:(7, 18) java: ';' expected
Error:(9, 1) java: class, interface, or enum expected
```

I can use this way to put values in the array:

```
test[0] = 1;
test[1] = 2;
test[2] = 3;
test[3] = 4;
// and so on.
```

I am just looking for a simple way to do that.

---

**Edit**

I know I can use this :

```
int[] test = {1,2,3,4};
```

But what I want is a simple way to put values in array after its initialization.

And one another thing : I am not looking for loops!

---

**Edit**

The answer @Python gave was what I was looking for!

Comment: please rewrite your question, after initialized array, only you can give value by position with help of loop, or a[i], when i=1,2,......N.

Comment: if you are doing this , `test = {1,2,3,4,5};` means you don't know what are valid statements as far as array initialization is concerned - this is not IDE issue but an invalid Java statement. Why putting values in array elements via loop doesn't look easier to you?

Comment: if you array length is dynamic, than without loop, you can go for recursive.

Comment: I am not familiar with C# but in Java, once you have allocated memory to an array variable , there is no one liner shorthand to put all values for that array. You will have to use API classes as listed in answer by Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by using Arrays's static method in one line:

```
Integer[] test = new Integer[10];
Arrays.<Integer>asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).toArray(test);
```

Note: using 'int' is also fine but then you to add explicit casting (int[])

Comment: This looks cool, thanks

Comment: Just a reminder for this approach: For most other approaches here, if `test` is shorter than the "initialization list", you will still populate into `test` with just enough elements (and ignore the rest from the "initialization list").  However, for this approach, it will be silently ignored and `test` will stay uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize an array, try using Array [Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

```
int[] test = new int[6];
int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

**OR**

```
int[] test = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Comment: If this is not you are looking for, you need to rewrite your question because it is unclear what your are looking for.

Comment: it seems he has edited his question, you may delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

After initializing you can't assign values all at once,
you can do it this way :

```
test[0]=1;
test[1]=2;
```

and likewise..
hope this will help

Comment: So there isn't an easier way to do that !?

Comment: just use a for loop for more convenience..

Comment: Sure, I know that, was just looking for some kinda initializer list after initialization!, Thanks.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){ test[i]=i+1; }   this is all u've been looking for.. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize using a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<test.length-1;i++){
 test[i]=i;
}
```

this will make the test array have, 0,1,2,3,4,5 as its contents;

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no other way than having a loop to populate your already-instantiated array.

However, you don't need to write the loop by yourself:

`System.arrayCopy()` does the work.  And one day JVM may decide to do something like `memcpy` to do the work, by using such kind of built-in functions, you may benefit from such JVM change without change in your source code.